# Deploy SSIS on Azure Portal

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database

I have already tried to deploy SSIS using AzureVM and it's working fine for us. Just want to explore other options.

1. Is it possible to deploy SSIS on Azure Sql Service **without using AzureVM**? If yes, then provide some guidance.
2. How to connect local (on-premises) database (For example. Oracle) from Azure SQL using SSIS **without using AzureVM**?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, this requires an Azure VM or an on premise installation of SSIS- SSIS as a Service is not an Azure offering at this time.
2. Azure SQL Database won't allow for [Linked Servers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) and, [elastic query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview) may not fit your use case; It may not be possible to do *from* Azure SQL. However, you could try defining one data source for SQL Azure and one for your on-prem database (or even Oracle) within SSIS and run your report on the data that way. [More about establishing data sources/connections.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can deploy your SSIS package on Azure by creating Integration Run-time in Data factory which will create a SSISDB and under SSISDB, Integration Service Catalog will be available.
SSIS Project deployment is available as of now on Integration Service Catalog.
For more details and steps, click below link-
[deploy-sql-server-integration-service-packages-to-azure-using-azure-data-factoryv2](https://prayagsql.wordpress.com/2017/12/31/deploy-sql-server-integration-servicesssis-packages-to-azure-using-azure-data-factoryv2/)